# Function is not accessible after onload event. "TypeError: {someFunctionName} is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a small and simple slider with Javascript. Because I want to be sure that the slider works when I load the javascript in the footer of the page. I added an `onload` event and copied the whole slider application inside the event. In the HTML I unfortunately have an inline `onclick` element in a tag. But since I have the code inside the onload scope the onclick doesn't work anymore. My idea is not to bind the event inline in the html but directly in the javascript. That should work. But I am also interested if it is possible to do it with the inline onclick.

**Question** What do I have to do so that the onclick element addresses the corresponding function within the `onclick` function?

```js
document.querySelector('body').onload = function() { 
  
  function init() {
    // ...
  }
  
  const f2 = function() {
    // ...
  }
  
  init();

  /* that will work */
  const anchorPrev = document.querySelector('.prev');
      anchorPrev.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('prev');
  });
  
  /* My question */
  function next() {
    console.log('next')
  }
};
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a class="next" onclick="next()">next (I'm curious to know if it works!?)</a><br/>
    <a class="prev">prev (Will work)</a>
</body>
```

Comment: It'd be better if you would just attach an event listener on your `onload` function. You got access to the `next` function right there.

Comment: `next` is defined inside a closure and not in the global scope. It would be better to use `addEventListener` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. It's better to wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event on the `window` object.
2. You're defining the function within the scope of the function, so it's not globally accessible. This means that the `onclick` can't see the function. Use a `let` variable, then set the function inside the listener callback like this:

```html
<button onclick="log()">click me</button>

<script>
    let log;

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log('loaded');
        log = () => console.log('clicked');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I thought about that for a moment too. It's good that you write it again. Thank you very much! 1up from me and there are probably not many more possibilities. I think it will be the accept answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add that the onload event = function next()

JavaSript code:

```
document.querySelector('body').onload = function() { 

  const a = document.querySelector('a')
  a.onclick = function next() {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('next')
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron, for your answer. I already knew that and had already hinted at it in my question. I was specifically only interested in the inline onclick option. @mstephen19 has written a good solution. However. Thanks for your correct answer. For that +1up from me :-)